# My code is not working! The traffic lights colour wont change

Tags: javascript

My code isn't working. The traffic light colours won't change. Please help me it's for my computing controlled assessment.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<h1> TRAFFIC LIGHTS </h1>

<img id="RED" src = "RED.jpg">

<script>
var lights = ["RED.jpg", "AMBER.jpg", "GREEN.jpg", "AMBER.jpg"]
var count = 0
function Changelights() {
document.getElementById("RED")src=lights[count]
    count = count + 1
    if(count === redlight.length){
        count = 0;
    }
}

</script>

<div>
<button type= "button" onclick= "Changelights()">Change Lights </button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you see the errors in your console? By pressing F12.

Comment: `document.getElementById("RED")src` is invalid syntax. It’s `document.getElementById("RED").src`. `redlight` isn’t defined anywhere. Did you mean `lights`?

Comment: document.getElementById("RED").src , missing . and redlight is undefined it should be lights

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors in your snippet.

- Start by storing the DOM element you're selecting into a variable. We're doing this with: `var light = document.getElementById("light")`. I also renamed the `id` into `light` to make it more explicit as the color will change.
- Then, you can change the `src` attribute using the `setAttribute` method.
- You can increment `count` as you're setting the attribute
- Finally, I used a ternary to check if count is equal to the length of the array. If so, we're setting it to 0
- Other:

  - it's better to put the `script` tag just before the `body` tag
  - it's conventional to use camelCase in JavaScript
  - we're starting count at 1 so it turns into orange on the first click

```html
<body>
 <h1> TRAFFIC LIGHTS </h1>
 <img id="light" src="http://faculty.washington.edu/miceal/lgw/red.JPG">
 <div>
  <button type= "button" onclick= "changeLights()">Change Lights </button>
 </div>
 <script>
  var lights = ["http://faculty.washington.edu/miceal/lgw/red.JPG", "http://webyogi.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/2880x1800-amber-orange-solid-color-background.jpg", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Color-Green.JPG"]
  var count = 1 // So it turns amber on the first click
  var light = document.getElementById("light")

  function changeLights() {
    light.setAttribute("src",lights[count++])
    count = count === lights.length ? 0 : count; // If count is the length of the array, we're setting it to 0. Else, we're incrementing it (it's called a ternary).
  }

 </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<img id="RED" src = "RED.jpg">

<script>
var lights = ["RED.jpg", "AMBER.jpg", "GREEN.jpg", "AMBER.jpg"]
var color = document.getElementById("RED");

function Changelights() 
{
for(var i = 0; i < lights.length; i++)
{
color.src=lights[i];

if(i == lights.length)
{
i = 0;
}
}
}

</script>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Code-only answers are less useful for future readers and don’t explain the OP’s mistake or how to approach the problem.